# MongoDB: Reduce array of objects into a single object by computing the average of each field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use the MongoDB aggregation API to aggregate some data daily.
The result of this aggregation is of this format:

```
[
  {
    aggDate: '2019-05-23',
    results: [
      {
        foo: 0.58,
        bar: 0.42
      }, {
        foo: 0.32,
        bar: 0.98
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The aggregation on the date is fine, but now I would like to aggregate the objects in the `results` array.

The result of this aggregation should be of the following format:

```
[
  {
    aggDate: '2019-05-23',
    result: {
      foo: 0.45 // avg of all the `foo`, here: (0.58 + 0.32) / 2
      bar: 0.7 // avg of all the `bar`, here: (0.42 + 0.98) / 2
    }
  }
]
```

My problem here is that the keys `foo` and `bar` can change/new fields can be added in `results` objects. To avoid recoding the query each time it occurs, I want to use some generic way to say to MongoDB

> Take this array of objects and reduce it into a single object where each value is the average of the same field in all objects.

I know the `$reduce` operator exists in MongoDB but I can't figure out how to use it and I am not even sure if it can help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and aggregate the data using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stages. You also need [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) and [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to work with dynamic keys. [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) is not an option here since keys are unknwon

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            aggDate: 1,
            results: {
                $map: { input: "$results", in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$results"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$results"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { aggDate: "$aggDate", k: "$results.k" },
            sum: { $sum: "$results.v" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            v: { $divide: [ "$sum", "$count" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.aggDate",
            results: { $push: { k: "$_id.k", v: "$v" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            aggDate: "$_id",
            results: { $arrayToObject: "$results" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fH-hrERJXuX)

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to use `$reduce`. Simply `$sum` can do the job.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "result": {
      "foo": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": "$results.foo" }, { "$size": "$results" }] },
      "bar": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": "$results.bar" }, { "$size": "$results" }] }
    }
  }}
])
```

**Update->** according to dynamic keys inside `results` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "aggDate": 1,
    "results": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$map": { "input": "$results", "in": { "$objectToArray": "$$this" }}
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "aggDate": 1,
    "result": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": { "input": { "$setUnion": ["$results.k"] },
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "fil": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$results",
                    "as": "d",
                    "cond": { "$eq": ["$$d.k", "$$m"] }
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "k": "$$m",
                "v": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": "$$fil.v" }, { "$size": "$$fil" }] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQXRNS17JuO)

With more simplified version and with single `$project` stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "aggDate": 1,
    "result": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "red": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$map": { "input": "$results", "in": { "$objectToArray": "$$this" }}
              },
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$map": { "input": { "$setUnion": ["$$red.k"] },
              "as": "m",
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "fil": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$$red",
                        "as": "d",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$d.k", "$$m"] }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "k": "$$m",
                    "v": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": "$$fil.v" }, { "$size": "$$fil" }] }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NnRS24b_hvB)

And both output as

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "aggDate": "2019-05-23",
    "result": {
      "bar": 0.7,
      "foho": 0.32,
      "foo": 0.58,
      "sdbar": 0.98
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to explicitly use foo and bar in the query.

Comment: @Korbraan Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. However, the query seems slower than with the @mickl solution.

Comment: @Korbraan Hmmm... Not possible. It is a single stage query. Where did you test it?

Comment: I have a local database with some test data (~3000 documents). 
I use Nodejs and Mongoose and I benchmarked the queries using the MongoDB database profiler.
However I have no index for now, it may change the result.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
not the most elegant but:

```
    { 
        "$unwind" : "$result"
    }, 
    { 
        "$addFields" : {
            "value" : {
                "$objectToArray" : "$result"
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : "$value"
    }, 
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null, 
            "length" : {
                "$sum" : 1.0
            }, 
            "total" : {
                "$sum" : "$value.v"
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$addFields" : {
            "avg" : {
                "$divide" : [
                    "$total", 
                    "$length"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you test that somehow ? I'm getting an exception when trying to run this solution. please take a look: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yh6ylcasOFj

Comment: my bad, i thought result is an object not an array