# Can't reduce a deeply nested array on MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregate

I've a Mongo database with documents like these one inside a collection:

```
{
   date:"2019-06-12T00:09:03.000Z",
   actions:{
      actionDate:"2019-06-12T00:15:25.000Z",
      data:{
         users:[
            [{gender:"Male",age:24},
             {gender:"Female",age:25}
            ],
            [{gender:"Male",age:34},
             {gender:"Male",age:26}
            ],
            [{gender:"Female",age:19},
             {gender:"Male",age:21}
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to summarize the users appearing inside the array `users` in a single document, like

```
{
   "date":"2019-06-12T00:09:03.000Z",
   "actionDate":"2019-06-12T00:15:25.000Z",
   "summary":{
      "countFemale":2,
      "meanFemaleAge":22,
      "countMale":4,
      "meanMaleAge":26.25
   }
}
```

Some considerations to be taken into account: there could be no cases for one gender and also, the `users` array might be limited to one or two arrays inside it.
I've tried to solve it using my, now I know, scarce knowledge of Mongo query language but it seems unsolvable to me. Thought this might be useful checking [MongoDB: Reduce array of objects into a single object by computing the average of each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279423/mongodb-reduce-array-of-objects-into-a-single-object-by-computing-the-average-o) but can't catch up with the idea.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: The question you mention is about reducing an array with dynamic field names.  [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation) should work for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Merge all arrays inside 'users' & push to 'summary' field */
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      actionDate: "$actions.actionDate",
      summary: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$actions.data.users",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$summary",
  },
  /** Group on 'date' to push data related to same date */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$date",
      actionDate: {$first: "$actionDate",},
      countFemale: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$summary.gender", "Female"]},1,0]}},
      countMale: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$summary.gender", "Male"]},1,0]}},
      meanFemaleAge: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$summary.gender", "Female"]},"$summary.age",0]}},
      meanMaleAge: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$summary.gender", "Male"]},"$summary.age",0]}}
    }
  },
  /** Re-create 'meanFemaleAge' & 'meanMaleAge' fields to add mean */
  {
    $addFields: {
      meanFemaleAge: {$cond: [{$ne: ["$meanFemaleAge", 0]},{$divide: ["$meanFemaleAge","$countFemale"]},0]},
      meanMaleAge: {$cond: [{$ne: ["$meanMaleAge", 0]},{$divide: ["$meanMaleAge","$countMale"]},0]},      
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tiJ7F8K741i)

**Note :** No matter what how you do this, I would suggest you to do not implement this kind of operations on entire collection with huge datasets.

Comment: @arlugones : Usually query performance depends on multiple factors like your DB server capacity, indexes, no.of docs. So if you wanted to make sure your query is running fine try to add `$explain` stage (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html) & check whether it's using proper indexes/which stage is performing least & couple other details by that you can assume what's going wrong & improve existing query..

Answer (score 1):

We need to perform `$reduce` operator.

In the first stage, we create separate arrays (`Male`|`Female`) and push users according to their gender.

In the second stage, we transform / calculate result.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "users": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$actions.data.users",
          initialValue: {
            "Male": [],
            "Female": []
          },
          in: {
            Male: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.Male",
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.gender",
                        "Male"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            Female: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.Female",
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.gender",
                        "Female"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: 1,
      actionDate: "$actions.actionDate",
      summary: {
        "countFemale": {
          $size: "$users.Female"
        },
        "meanFemaleAge": {
          $avg: "$users.Female.age"
        },
        "countMale": {
          $size: "$users.Male"
        },
        "meanMaleAge": {
          $avg: "$users.Male.age"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tRl0FXLQTLK)

Comment: Excellent! Much obliged, sir!

Comment: To be honest... I'd liked the previous approach better.